# Arduino device controlled by c# program

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm working on a small project (http://www.instructables.com/id/Digispark-Volume-Control/) that uses a digispark and a rotary encoder to control media(volume,mute,pause,next,prev). The volume is controlled by the rotation of the rotary encoder and the other stuff are controlled by pressing the button in a specific way: 1 click is for pause, 2 clicks is for mute, short hold for previous song and long hold for next song.

I am asking how would i approach using c# and arduino together to control these stuff dynamically (setup and change what these events that i stated above do, and possibly if i get far with this, add something like a macro editor that uses patterns from the rotary encoders to do stuff). 
example for the macro-editor like idea: if i do 2 short clicks for lets say max of 200ms and a turn to the left with the rotary encoder lock the computer.

I am trying to accomplish something like the griffin powermate(https://griffintechnology.com/us/powermate), have a software that sets up what the device does and the device to follow the software

This is the current code i got for the device, it only has the basic features for controling the media:

```
#include "TrinketHidCombo.h"

#define PIN_ENCODER_A 0
#define PIN_ENCODER_B 2
#define PIN_BUTTON 1
#define TRINKET_PINx  PINB

static uint8_t enc_prev_pos = 0;
static uint8_t enc_flags    = 0;

void setup()
{
  // set pins as input with internal pull-up resistors enabled
  pinMode(PIN_ENCODER_A, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_ENCODER_B, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(PIN_ENCODER_A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_ENCODER_B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON, HIGH);

  TrinketHidCombo.begin(); // start the USB device engine and enumerate

  // get an initial reading on the encoder pins
  if (digitalRead(PIN_ENCODER_A) == LOW) {
    enc_prev_pos |= (1 << 0);
  }
  if (digitalRead(PIN_ENCODER_B) == LOW) {
    enc_prev_pos |= (1 << 1);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  int8_t enc_action = 0; // 1 or -1 if moved, sign is direction

  // note: for better performance, the code will now use
  // direct port access techniques
  // http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation
  uint8_t enc_cur_pos = 0;
  // read in the encoder state first
  if (bit_is_clear(TRINKET_PINx, PIN_ENCODER_A)) {
    enc_cur_pos |= (1 << 0);
  }
  if (bit_is_clear(TRINKET_PINx, PIN_ENCODER_B)) {
    enc_cur_pos |= (1 << 1);
  }

  // if any rotation at all
  if (enc_cur_pos != enc_prev_pos)
  {
    if (enc_prev_pos == 0x00)
    {
      // this is the first edge
      if (enc_cur_pos == 0x01) {
        enc_flags |= (1 << 0);
      }
      else if (enc_cur_pos == 0x02) {
        enc_flags |= (1 << 1);
      }
    }

    if (enc_cur_pos == 0x03)
    {
      // this is when the encoder is in the middle of a "step"
      enc_flags |= (1 << 4);
    }
    else if (enc_cur_pos == 0x00)
    {
      // this is the final edge
      if (enc_prev_pos == 0x02) {
        enc_flags |= (1 << 2);
      }
      else if (enc_prev_pos == 0x01) {
        enc_flags |= (1 << 3);
      }

      // check the first and last edge
      // or maybe one edge is missing, if missing then require the middle state
      // this will reject bounces and false movements
      if (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 0) && (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 2) || bit_is_set(enc_flags, 4))) {
        enc_action = 1;
      }
      else if (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 2) && (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 0) || bit_is_set(enc_flags, 4))) {
        enc_action = 1;
      }
      else if (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 1) && (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 3) || bit_is_set(enc_flags, 4))) {
        enc_action = -1;
      }
      else if (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 3) && (bit_is_set(enc_flags, 1) || bit_is_set(enc_flags, 4))) {
        enc_action = -1;
      }

      enc_flags = 0; // reset for next time
    }
  }

  // Get button event and act accordingly
  int b = checkButton();
  if (b == 1) clickEvent();
  if (b == 2) doubleClickEvent();
  if (b == 3) holdEvent();
  if (b == 4) longHoldEvent();

  enc_prev_pos = enc_cur_pos;

  if (enc_action > 0) {
    TrinketHidCombo.pressMultimediaKey(MMKEY_VOL_UP);
  }
  else if (enc_action < 0) {
    TrinketHidCombo.pressMultimediaKey(MMKEY_VOL_DOWN);
  }
  else {
    TrinketHidCombo.poll(); // do nothing, check if USB needs anything done
  }
}

//=================================================
// Events to trigger

void clickEvent() {
  TrinketHidCombo.pressMultimediaKey(MMKEY_PLAYPAUSE);
}
void doubleClickEvent() {
  TrinketHidCombo.pressMultimediaKey(MMKEY_MUTE);
}
void holdEvent() {
  TrinketHidCombo.pressMultimediaKey(MMKEY_SCAN_PREV_TRACK);
}
void longHoldEvent() {
  TrinketHidCombo.pressMultimediaKey(MMKEY_SCAN_NEXT_TRACK);
}

int debounce = 20;          // ms debounce period to prevent flickering when pressing or releasing the button
int DCgap = 500;            // max ms between clicks for a double click event
int holdTime = 1000;        // ms hold period: how long to wait for press+hold event
int longHoldTime = 1500;    // ms long hold period: how long to wait for press+hold event

// Button variables
boolean buttonVal = HIGH;   // value read from button
boolean buttonLast = HIGH;  // buffered value of the button's previous state
boolean DCwaiting = false;  // whether we're waiting for a double click (down)
boolean DConUp = false;     // whether to register a double click on next release, or whether to wait and click
boolean singleOK = true;    // whether it's OK to do a single click
long downTime = -1;         // time the button was pressed down
long upTime = -1;           // time the button was released
boolean ignoreUp = false;   // whether to ignore the button release because the click+hold was triggered
boolean waitForUp = false;        // when held, whether to wait for the up event
boolean holdEventPast = false;    // whether or not the hold event happened already
boolean longHoldEventPast = false;// whether or not the long hold event happened already

int checkButton() {
  int event = 0;
  buttonVal = digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON);
  // Button pressed down
  if (buttonVal == HIGH && buttonLast == LOW && (millis() - upTime) > debounce)
  {
    downTime = millis();
    ignoreUp = false;
    waitForUp = false;
    singleOK = true;
    holdEventPast = false;
    longHoldEventPast = false;
    if ((millis() - upTime) < DCgap && DConUp == false && DCwaiting == true)  DConUp = true;
    else  DConUp = false;
    DCwaiting = false;
  }
  // Button released
  // DOUBLE CLICK
  else if (buttonVal == HIGH && buttonLast == HIGH && (millis() - downTime) > debounce)
  {
    if (not ignoreUp)
    {
      upTime = millis();
      if (DConUp == false) DCwaiting = true;
      else
      {
        event = 2;
        DConUp = false;
        DCwaiting = false;
        singleOK = false;
      }
    }
  }
  // Test for normal click event: DCgap expired
  if ( buttonVal == LOW && (millis() - upTime) >= DCgap && DCwaiting == true && DConUp == false && singleOK == true && event != 2)
  {
    event = 1;
    DCwaiting = false;
  }
  // Test for hold
  if (buttonVal == HIGH && (millis() - downTime) >= holdTime) {
    // Trigger "normal" hold
    if (not holdEventPast)
    {
      event = 3;
      waitForUp = true;
      ignoreUp = true;
      DConUp = false;
      DCwaiting = false;
      //downTime = millis();
      holdEventPast = true;
    }
    // Trigger "long" hold
    if ((millis() - downTime) >= longHoldTime)
    {
      if (not longHoldEventPast)
      {
        event = 4;
        longHoldEventPast = true;
      }
    }
  }
  buttonLast = buttonVal;
  return event;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot run C# code on the Arduino itself that code needs to be running on a PC (or Raspberry Pi or similar using .NET Core).

So that means you need a way to communicate between the two. Your options are:

1. Send messages back and forth over a serial port (serial over USB) (easiest since you are probably already using one to program your Arduino).
2. Use WIFI or Ethernet and create a WebAPI endpoint that the Arduino calls into to deliver messages and to get results.
3. Use some other communication mechanism like Bluetooth.

Alternatively, if you have a device like the Trinket that only supports keyboard emulation over USB you would need to pick some unused keycodes for it to send and then have your application hook into the global events to handle them (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/) - unless of course you application is in the foreground in which case you can just read input from the keyboard as the device sends it.

Comment: Let me explain some more, the digispark uses a usb and simulates a keyboard(that's how i control the media controls) the c# software will be running on the computer that the device is connected to. so no need of wifi or ethernet or any webapis. Possible way to tackle this would be using the com ports but i need some help here that's why i asked this question

Comment: @DavidAnastasov - yes, so serial over USB. Just have the Arduino send messages to the PC and use a `SerialPort` in C# to listen to them.

Comment: I know my way around c# but i'm pretty new to all this aruino stuff so i have no idea how to handle this, any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidAnastasov Ah, the Trinket can't do serial, the library makes it act like a keyboard. So what you need to do in C# would be to hook the global keyboard events and handle them for special keys that you send.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but i can't seem to find these unused key codes so i can hook them. Can you give me a link or something because googling gives no results

Comment: @DavidAnastasov I haven't tried them, but I assume some of the codes in this list could be used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx